# How is the message considered in the STROBE-based Schnorr signature example?

Tags: implementation, schnorr-signature, sponge

I've been studying the Schnorr signature scheme and recently came across an example that uses the STROBE protocol. In the classic version of Schnorr signatures, the challenge e is calculated as e = H(m || r), where m is the message, r is an ephemeral value, and H is a cryptographic hash function. However, in the STROBE-based version of the Schnorr signature scheme, it seems that the challenge is generated based on the public key A and the ephemeral value R, with no mention of the message.

Here's the [STROBE-based Schnorr signature example from paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/003.pdf) (P.11):

```
// Alice has a private key k, from which she derives a secret exponent a by running
KEY[sym-key](k); a ← PRF[derive-key](b bytes)

//  When Alice needs to sign a STROBE context, she first begins
the signature using a AD[sig-scheme](name) operation
AD[sig-scheme](name)

//  She then needs a pseudorandom
value r. She calculates this determinsitically by copying the context and running
KEY[sym-key](k); 
r ← PRF[sig-determ](b bytes)

//  She calculates R := g^r and runs
AD[pubkey](A); CLR[sig-eph](R); 
c ← PRF[sig-chal](b bytes);
ENC[sig-resp](r + ac mod p);

// To verify the signature, Bob runs
AD[pubkey](A); 
R ← CLR[sig-eph](b_G bytes);
c ← PRF[sig-chal](b bytes);
s ← recv-ENC[sig-resp](log256(p) bytes)

// Bob then checks that R = g^s/A^c. This holds because g^s = g^(r+ac) = R · A^c
```

Notably, P.6 outline each of operations in STROBE
P.9 specify the usage of operation syntax. `ENC[app-ciphertext](“hello”)` mean the two operations
`meta-CLR([[0x03, 0x05, 0x00]]); ENC(“hello”)`

Can someone help me understand how the message is taken into account in the STROBE-based version of Schnorr signatures?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the classic version of Schnorr signatures, the challenge $e$ is calculated as $e = H(m\mathbin\|r)$, where $m$ is the message, $r$ is an ephemeral value, and $H$ is a cryptographic hash function.

Yes. My reading is that in [STROBE's Schnorr signature](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/003.pdf#page=11)

- The message $m$ to sign is essentially what's noted `b bytes` in the question, and gets hashed in the step $\mathtt{PRF}[\operatorname{sig-chal}](b\text{ bytes})$ of the paper.
- The ephemeral value $r$ is what's noted `R`.
- The challenge $e$ is what's noted `c`.
- It's actually computed $e=H(A,r,m)$, where $A$ is the public key, noted `A`; and the notation for $H$ is masking some formatting and domain separation constants beside mere concatenation. Hashing $A$ *“is an inexpensive way to alleviate concerns that several public keys could be attacked simultaneously”*, as the [ed25519 paper](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/ed25519-20110926.pdf#page=10) puts it.